# "Unfriendly Number" challenge

Tags: haskell, time-limit-exceeded

I tried to solve the [Unfriendly Number](https://www.interviewstreet.com/challenges/dashboard/#problem/4f7272a8b9d15) problem on InterviewStreet:

> There is one friendly number, K, and N unfriendly numbers. We want to find
>   how many numbers are there which exactly divide the friendly number,
>   but does not divide any of the unfriendly numbers.
>
> \$1 \le N \le 10^6\$
>
> \$1 \le K \le 10^13\$
>
> \$1 \le\$ unfriendly numbers \$\le 10^{18}\$

The algorithm is quite simple:

1. Find the set S. The set of gcd's of each unfriendly number with the friendly
   number.
2. Find the set of divisors of the friendly number.
3. Check if a divisor of the friendly number is a divisor of any element in S.

My code, where `u` is the list of unfriendly numbers, `k` is the friendly number. `nubOrd` is the `O(n log n)` time version of `nub`.

```
test u k = length $ filter (not) $ map try divisors
  where try t = or $ map (t `divides` ) (nubOrd $ map (gcd k) u)
        divisors = concat [ [i,div k i] | i<-[1..floor $ sqrt $ fromIntegral k], 
                                          i `divides` k]
d `divides` n = n `mod` d == 0
```

This code exceeds the time limit. The Java version of this algorithm solves the problem fine. Are there any ways to improve this code or is Haskell too slow for solving this problem?

Comment: It might be more efficient to replace the `length . filter not . map try` chain with a fold like `foldl (\count t -> if try t then count + 1 else count) 0` (probably with more strictness). But it's unlikely to make that much difference, since GHC is pretty smart.

Comment: can we see your `nubOrd`? You compile it with -O2 right?

Comment: the nubOrd is the one here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3100764/303863

Answer (score 5):

Your divisors generation is lacking. As explained e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12052561/849891), you should generate them from a number's prime factorization. It is much faster that way.

You may try using `rem` instead of `mod`.

Also try making `(nubOrd $ map (gcd k) u)` a separate expression and name it to ensure sharing, giving your function a concrete type signature too.

**update** so I tried my own advice and it only made the code run slower at the interviewstreet servers. The only reason I'm not removing this, is that the advice itself (and link) about divisor generation is valid in general. But here, it did not help improve the run time of *this algorithm*. The OP states that *same algorithm* in Java got through...

Comment: InterviewStreet may not compile Haskell code with -O2.